# How to allow a div to expand dynamically upon content instead of preset height?

Tags: jquery, menu, dynamic-content

I am not comfortable with my manual preset of the DIV height, when the height should really be dynamic. I worry that someone will change the font size or font itself; so I think my current solution is flimsy. But I can see no other way of dynamically setting the DIV height to automatically match the content within. Any help is appreciated.

Here is an example of what I have working currently: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qkwL2/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qkwL2/7/

Measure first. Then animate.

Also use as few `$` as possible. Every `$` adds another jQuery object to memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do animation like that,  than you are pretty much forced to set an explicit height (I am not aware of any other way).  One thing you might want to consider though, is a routine to calculate the height based on the contents of the div (ie, iterate through the list of anchor tags, and calculate a height for each of those, then add in your padding).  That way it is guaranteed to always show the entire div's contents.

Comment: +1 or put the initially hidden elements in a container and get the height of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the content that you want appearing on hover with a class, hide it with `display:none` and slide that down instead using jqueries `slideDown` method. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qkwL2/6/).